# groovy next() date issue

Tags: date, groovy, iterator, soapui

I am trying to add a groovy script in SoapUI to find tomorrow's date using `next()` in current date.
I am getting the date as expected for all other dates except if the date is 19.

```
def TodaysDate = new java.util.Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.info ">>>>>>>>>> TodaysDate="+TodaysDate
log.info TodaysDate.next()
```

Output:

> Wed Jul 19 14:34:29 EDT 2017:INFO:>>>>>>>>>> TodaysDate=2017-07-19
>   Wed Jul 19 14:34:29 EDT 2017:INFO:2017-07-1:

I tried this also.

```
def Today = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())
log.info Today
NextDay = Today.next()
log.info NextDay
```

Output:

> Wed Jul 19 14:43:38 EDT 2017:INFO:2017-07-19
>   Wed Jul 19 14:43:38 EDT 2017:INFO:2017-07-1:

This `next()` iterator works fine for other dates. Can you help me understand what I am doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format()` method returns a `String`. And when you call `next()` on a `String`, it [increments the last character](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_next.htm). So, character `9` [is incremented](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#next()) to the next unicode value, becoming `:`.

If you want your dates in a specific format, first you call `next()` in a `Date` object, then you format it:

```
def TodaysDate = new java.util.Date()
log.info ">>>>>>>>>> TodaysDate="+TodaysDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.info TodaysDate.next().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

The will print `TodaysDate=2017-07-19` and the next date as `2017-07-20`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's worth using [`TimeCategory`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) in your case? Take a look at this simple code sample:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

use (TimeCategory) {
    println new Date() + 1.day
}
```

It works fine with any date. Test it with today's date (2017-07-19) - adding `1.day` will give you 2017-07-20. Hope it helps.

Comment: Even without TimeCategory, `new Date() + 1` will add a day to the date. TimeCategory is useful when you want to add non-day units, though.